# How to call Business Related List Web Part from my JavaScript function?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, web-part, jquery

I want to fetch the data using Business Related List Web Part.I want to call this web part from my JavaScript function how can i do this?

Comment: Do you mean "Business Data Web Parts"? Also what do you mean by "call this web part"?

Comment: Yes Business Data Web Parts. I want to show that to this webpart when i click on button.

Comment: You can use Javasacript to `hide` the webpart when page onLoad. Then `show` the webpart on button click.

Comment: Hey i am not hiding the web part. I want to call web when i click on my button. I pass the parameter to call this function after that this web part fetch record. It do like when we create the connection between web part.